# Cpanel Nodejs CRUD REST API giving response as "Incomplete response received from application" using Mysql DB

Tags: node.js, cpanel

When i create a localhost nodejs CRUD API i am able to make post request.But when i deployed it in cpanel using nodejs software "Incomplete response received from application"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Please share more information as my preliminary guess is that  if you are using MongoDB then you cant run it on shared hosting you should use some other DB like Atlas MongoDB or Mlab
I recommend you host it on Heroku as its also free

- [Deploy APP to Heroku](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/hosting-node-js-app-on-heroku-in-less-than-5-mins-bc7ce244c8d0)
- Use Any thirParty mongoDB service
- [Test your CRUD API](https://www.postman.com/)